# Jmeter JDBC Request returns "Invalid operation for forward only resultset : last" when use "Count Records" on OUT REF CURSOR

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jmeter

I'm new to JMeter and Java, and I need to load test stored procedure that returns Oracle Ref Cursor.

I use JMeter ver 3.1, Here is a JDBC request, with the callable statement to call the procedure as following:

begin test_pkg.test_proc_1('abc',?); end;

```
Parameter Values : ResultSet
Types: OUT -10
variable names: crsr
Handle ResultSet: Count Records
```

The test plan runs successfully, but I got the following response error in View Results tree:

**Response message:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation for forward only resultset : last
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JavaDoc](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#last--) you cannot call last() on a FORWARD_ONLY ResultSet and a ref cursor result set is FORWARD_ONLY.

Comment: Thanks Douglas Surber. Is there any change on JMeter JDBC Request that I can do to convert this output to some other type that allow me to get the total count of records returned.